# Add a servlet will disable all servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to JavaEE and I have a problem with java servlet.

I have a servlet works well. Then I want to add another one. However, once I added the second one, the first one no longer works and server always respond 404 without any content (Normally the 404 will return with a page, not it is just a white page)

There must be some problems with the second servlet and If I disable one line of code the first servlet works. However I haven't seen any error messages

Can someone tell me the reason of this and how can I debug the program. (I cannot debug the program because the request cannot map to the second servlet and no breakpoints work)

Thanks a lot.

Fallflame

**UPDATE**

Now it works, thanks to Danail Alexiev remind me that it is may be a configuration problem. I found an error that said "cannot convert the project to dynamic web 2.5" and I just do maven -> update project then it works.

Still cannot understand why.

This is the one line code that let all servlets don't works :

```
ServiceMetadata edm = odata.createServiceMetadata(new DemoEdmProvider(), new ArrayList<EdmxReference>());
```

all copied from Apache Olingo tutorial.

Comment: It would be easier to detect the problem if you provide you Servlet source code and configuration

Comment: can you show the one line of code you are talking about

Comment: Please post your code. Make sure your second servlet is properly mapped in web.xml